# How to track event on onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can i track events if it is close tab, refresh page or button click on           onbeforeunload?

I am clicking a button which is from iframe and it is redirecting me to some other page. It is cross domain call so can't set

```
 $window.top.onbeforeunload = null;
```

I don't want to call onbeforeunload on button click. Please provide me any solution?

Comment: Not able to understand your problem, try to explan with a piece of code.

Comment: I have a parent site where i am using iframe for some other site let us name it as child site. Code written is in angular. In parent site i have used angular.element(window).on('beforeunload', function). Now when i make request to change url from child site, "beforeunload" calls from parent site. I want to disable beforeunload in this case.